# How to run this query on Joomla DB using CRON job?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, cron

I have created these queries (and tested them in PhpMyAdmin) and now need to run them on my Joomla! DB using a CRON job calling a .php file.

```
DELETE FROM j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups WHERE id IN(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SG.id FROM j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups SG
    JOIN j25_acym_user AU on AU.cms_id = SG.virtuemart_user_id
    JOIN j25_acym_user_has_list AUL ON  AUL.user_id = AU.id
    where SG.virtuemart_shoppergroup_id = 10 AND (AUL.list_id = 13 AND AUL.status=0) 
) as P
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups (virtuemart_user_id, virtuemart_shoppergroup_id) 
SELECT * FROM( SELECT cms_id, '10'
 FROM j25_acym_user_has_list AUL 
left JOIN j25_acym_user AU ON  AUL.user_id = AU.id
left JOIN j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups SG  on AU.cms_id = SG.virtuemart_user_id
where SG.virtuemart_shoppergroup_id IS NULL AND (AUL.list_id = 13 AND AUL.status=1)) as foo
ON duplicate KEY update
virtuemart_shoppergroup_id=virtuemart_shoppergroup_id;
```

How do I turn this into a (or 2) working PHP files which I can call upon using WGET?

Comment: Do you want to run query outside Joomla files ?

Comment: I am not sure, what is best? I thought to place the PHP file somewhere in my administrator folder and run it from there. But I am open for any suggestion.

Comment: you delet query doens need the outer SELECT * FROM it is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include joomla files framework.php and defines.php when you run query via cron job try the following code

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . '');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php');
require_once (JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php'); 
$db     = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = 'DELETE FROM j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups WHERE id IN(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SG.id FROM j25_virtuemart_vmuser_shoppergroups SG
    JOIN j25_acym_user AU on AU.cms_id = SG.virtuemart_user_id
    JOIN j25_acym_user_has_list AUL ON  AUL.user_id = AU.id
    where SG.virtuemart_shoppergroup_id = 10 AND (AUL.list_id = 13 AND AUL.status=0) 
) as P
)';
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Comment: I guess I have to add <?php at the top? I created a php file and placed in the \cli folder. created a CRON calling the PHP file using the PHP parser. But I do not see any result. When I run the QUERY using MYSQL workbench the record is being deleted.

Comment: @user3748911 you should check cron job that file or not